# Not calling the appropriate constructor

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class String
{
    protected:
        enum {SZ= 80};
        char str[SZ];
    public:
        String (){str[0]='\0';}
        String(char s[])
        {
            strcpy(str,s);
        }
        void display() const
        {  
            cout<<str;
        }
        operator char*()
        {
            return str;
        }
};
class Pstring : public String
{
    public:
        Pstring(char s[])
        {
            if(strlen(s)>SZ-1)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<SZ-1;j++)
                {
                    str[j]=s[j];
                }
                str[SZ-1]='\0';
            }
            else
            {String(s);}
        }
};
int main()
{
  Pstring s2 ="This is a strong string.";
  cout<<"\ns2="; s2.display();
return 0;
}
```

`s2.display()` returns blank. Upon debugging it's is found that `String(s)` in Pstring calls the no-argument constructor in the String class. I understand it as a constructor with one argument and thus `String(char s[])` should've been called. What is this behavior?

Comment: You can only initialize the base class using the initializer list.

Comment: `String` which does any kind of IO operation is a very bad code (Single Responsibility Principle).

Comment: Enabling more warnings provides "warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of 's' ". Also, you can't call the constructor; the language does that for you when an object is created.

Comment: beware of the `String(char s[])` ctor: if the input string is longer than 80, you are going to corrupt memory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet

```
        else
        {String(s);}
```

does not make a sense.

This line

```
String(s);
```

is a declaration of the variable `s` of the type `String` with the scope of the compound operator of the else part of the if statement.

Pay attention to that this constructor

```
Pstring(char s[])
```

calls implicitly the default constructor of the class String before the control will be passed to the body of the constructor. That is the body of the constructor gets the control only after all sub-objects of the created object of the derived class will be created.

You should place the check of the passed string in the constructor of the class `String`.

For example in the class `String` you could define the constructor with parameter the following way

```
    String( const char s[] )
    {
        strncpy( str, s, SZ );
        str[SZ - 1] = '\0';
    }
```

And the constructor in the derived class could be defined like

```
    Pstring( const char s[] ) : String( s )
    {
    }
```

Comment: Why does ` Pstring(char s[])` call the constructor of the String class. I mean there is no initialization list. Shouldn't it first step into the body of itself?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed At first objects of the class including sub-objects of its base class are created and only after that the body of the constructor of the derived class  gets the control.